# Java Spring hibernate HQL where clause not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, join, where-clause

I have a HQL query with a JOIN but the where clause (instrPrice.date BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo )  on the joined entity doesn't work. The query always returns all the records of instrumentPrice instead of limiting the result by the dates.

NamedQuery

```java
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllPrices", 
        query = "SELECT DISTINCT taPat FROM TaPatternInstrument taPat "
                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH taPat.instrument instr "
                + "LEFT JOIN instr.instrumentPriceList instrPrice "
                + "WHERE taPat.id = :taPatternInstrumentId "
                + "AND instrPrice.date BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo ")
```

Service which calls the Query

```java
public TaPatternInstrument findAllPrices(int taPatternInstrumentId, LocalDate dateFrom,  LocalDate dateTo) {

   TypedQuery<TaPatternInstrument> typedQuery = createNamedQuery("findAllPrices", 
        TaPatternInstrument.class);
   typedQuery.setParameter("taPatternInstrumentId", taPatternInstrumentId);
   typedQuery.setParameter("dateFrom", dateFrom);
   typedQuery.setParameter("dateTo", dateTo);
   return typedQuery.getSingleResult(); 
}
```

Entities

```java
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

   @Id  
   @Column(name = "id")     
   @GeneratedValue(strategy =
                GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   protected int id; ... 
}

public class TaPatternInstrument extends BaseEntity {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumn(name = "instrument_id", nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = 
            "tapatterninstrument_instrument_fk"))
   private Instrument instrument;

}


public class Instrument extends BaseEntity {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instrument", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<InstrumentPrice> instrumentPriceList;

}
```

### Generated SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT tapatterni0_.id  AS id1_34_0_, 
...
FROM   tapatterninstrument tapatterni0_ 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN instrument instrument1_ 
                    ON tapatterni0_.instrument_id = instrument1_.id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN instrumentprice instrument2_ 
                    ON instrument1_.id = instrument2_.instrument_id 
WHERE  tapatterni0_.id = ? 
       AND ( instrument2_.date BETWEEN ? AND ? )
```

Comment: Did you try to use any other types of date? Is this issue related only to LocalDate or not?

Comment: Which is your dataset? Or an example of that? And also, did you use this query in a DMBS with native sql to check if the query is ok?

Comment: I have to use LocalDate because in the entity  InstrumentPrice, the property date is defines as follow:  private LocalDate date;

Comment: I've added the generated sql  at the end of the posted question.

Comment: What is the error it is giving? Stacktrace ?

Comment: There is no exception

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. [ask]

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add a FETCH on instrumentPriceList : **LEFT JOIN FETCH instr.instrumentPriceList instrPrice**

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findAllPrices", 
query = "SELECT DISTINCT taPat FROM TaPatternInstrument taPat "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH taPat.instrument instr "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH instr.instrumentPriceList instrPrice "
        + "LEFT JOIN taPat.taPatternInstrumentPriceList taPatpr "
        + "WHERE taPat.id = :taPatternInstrumentId "
        + "AND instrPrice.date BETWEEN :dateFrom AND :dateTo ")
```

The FETCH forces Hibernate to retrieve the Entity (InstrumentPrice) immediately at the first DB request.  And thus the where clause is taken into account.
Without FETCH, the Entity InstrumentPrice is only retrieved from the DB when the method  getInstrumentPriceList of the Entity Instrument is called (an additional call to the DB is performed).  And with this additional call to the DB, the where clause is not taken into account anymore, thus retrieving all records from Entity instrumentPrice.